# The "shield" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Prompted by [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196104/why-are-arduino-peripherals-called-shields) question, I'm bringing up the [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield) tag. Searching "shield" under tags brings up: [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield), [shielding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shielding), and [arduino-shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield).

[shielding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shielding) is exactly what you would expect it to be, referring to EMC. [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield) seems to be a synonym of [arduino-shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield). I don't have the tag rep to propose a synonym, but why not merge them? Thoughts?

Comment: I'd expect `shield` to be synonymous for `shielding`, not for `arduino-shield`.

Comment: I think that for all practical purposes (=ardweenies) it needs at least some tag guidance: "For Arduino shields use..."

Comment: @RespawnedFluff That assumes they'll read it. Considering that entire ecosystem is built around not having to understand anything, I doubt it makes a lick of difference.

Comment: Can we not with insults, minor or otherwise :|

Comment: @Passerby: If you're referring to "ardweenies" I picked it up from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/196109/54580

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I'll propose:

1. Retag all questions tagged [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield) that refer to EMC shielding to [shielding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shielding)
2. Get rid of any non Arduino shield questions tagged [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield)
3. Merge [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield) into [arduino-shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield) and  <strike>make [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield) a synonym mapping to [arduino-shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield).</strike>
4. Change the [arduino-shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield) [wiki][1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/arduino/info) to include a reference to [shielding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shielding)

I'm suggesting that we make [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield) map to the Arduino usage to reduce workload. If you look at the *majority* of the questions in [shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shield), they are Arduino. I suspect EMC questioners would be more likely to distinguish between the two usages, and would result in the fewest false taggings.

(upvote/downvote as you see fit, and I'll revisit this in a bit.)

---

I ended up retagging 3 out of the 34 tagged questions that were EMC related, and I merged the remainder into [arduino-shield](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-shield). The shield tag should delete itself automatically in a day or so as long as nobody adds a new question. We'll try it this way and see if it sticks. Below is an image of the tag dialogue after getting rid of the shield tag:

[image]

Comment: It would be much nicer if we had a mechanism that when someone tries to use shield, they are forced to chose between shielded and arduino-shield.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Wouldn't that happen automatically once the `shield` tag is removed?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: the proposal is to make shield a synonym, so people would still be able to use it. Even if we remove it, then I think it can be recreated unless it is blocked, but even then it just cant be used and there is no userfriendly "did you mean" mechanism

Comment: Sorry, I have misread the answer (and mis-voted it as a consequence). What I meant was, once the tag is removed, the asker typing "shield" in the tags field will be offered both `shielding` and `arduino-shield` to pick from. Isn't that user-friendly enough?

Comment: We could try just deleting the shield tag instead of making a synonym. That would probably give the right behavior, but it doesn't take much to resurrect a tag

Comment: Shielding seems unintuitive to me.  It's a shame ro remove a perfectly good tag for a common usage and give it up to jargon.  I'd rather see the ambiguity stay in place

Comment: @ScottSeidman  Part of this is purely organizational - we don't distinguish between (EMC) shields and shielding in tagged questions. As a result, I consider the *usage* synonymous. Either that, or we have to dig through and make a distinction between the two terms. Take a look at the edited post to see what happens when you type 'shield' into the tag list when asking a question.